# Recreate Crosstab in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, crosstab

I have a table that's like this:

```
FILENO  CODE    FIELD
FILE1   *CODE1  SOK
FILE1   *CODE2  AUTO
FILE1   *CODE3  CTY
FILE2   *CODE1  SOK
FILE2   *CODE2  AR
FILE2   *CODE3  CTN
FILE3   *CODE1  SOKN
FILE3   *CODE2  AUTO
FILE3   *CODE3  CTN
```

That I'd like to recreate in a view or new table like this:

```
FILENO  *CODE1  *CODE2  *CODE3
FILE1   SOK     AUTO    CTY
FILE2   SOK     AR      CTN    
FILE3   SOKN    AUTO    CTN
```

Essentially a cross-tab query but i'm not sure how to accomplish this in SSMS.

Any pointers?

Comment: What you need is `PIVOT`

Comment: I figured that part out but can't figure out how it's used.

Comment: And how `CODE2` for `FILE1` become `12/15/2016`??

Comment: Your data doesn't support your output. All `*CODE1` look like dates. `*CODE3` looks like names. Not sure what `*CODE2` is, maybe a State abbreviation?

Comment: I updated my example.  Each "CODE" is a result of a test and can only have specific results, which i know.  let me know if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT [FILENO],
MAX(CASE CODE WHEN '*CODE1' THEN FIELD END) AS [*CODE1],
MAX(CASE CODE WHEN '*CODE2' THEN FIELD END) AS [*CODE2],
MAX(CASE CODE WHEN '*CODE3' THEN FIELD END) AS [*CODE3]
FROM [your_table_name]
GROUP BY [FILENO];
```

Or you can use a dynamic sql query for more efficiency.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT [FILENO], ' 
                + STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ', MAX(CASE [CODE] 
                WHEN ''' + [CODE] + ''' 
                THEN [FIELD] END) AS [' + [CODE] + ']'
                FROM [your_table_name]
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '')
                +' FROM [your_table_name] GROUP BY [FIELDNO]';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I was close and this filled in the gaps!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic [`PIVOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

```
Select [FILENO],[*CODE1],[*CODE2],[*CODE3]
From   (Select FileNo,Code,Field from YourTable) A
Pivot (max(FIELD) For CODE in ([*CODE1],[*CODE2],[*CODE3]) ) p
```

**Returns**

```
FILENO  *CODE1  *CODE2  *CODE3
FILE1   SOK     AUTO    CTY
FILE2   SOK     AR      CTN
FILE3   SOKN    AUTO    CTN
```

**For a Dynamic version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Code]) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [FILENO],' + @SQL + '
From (Select FileNo,Code,Field from YourTable) A
Pivot (max(FIELD) For [CODE] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: I originally tried this but it didn't group it by FILENO.

Comment: @Niq6 do you have extra fields in your table?

Comment: yes.  I'm guessing thats the reason why.  But the other answer worked fine. i'm going to go that route.  thanks john!

Comment: @Niq6 just replace YourTable with a sub-query (Select FileMp,Code,Field from YourTable) A